# One RewriteRule for both HTML and PHP redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have these 2 rewrite rules. But is there a way to combine into 1 rule, where the redirect will occur whether the URL is .php or .html?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.com$
RewriteRule ^about\.html\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.url\.com\/about\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.com$
RewriteRule ^about\.php\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.url\.com\/about\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them using regex alternation:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.com$
RewriteRule ^about\.(html|php)/?(.*)$ http://www.url.com/about/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Got an internal server error page.

Comment: Try now edited rue and do check Apache error.log if you still get 500

Comment: Also if you had other rules do post those rules in your questions as well.

Comment: Thanks - that revision seemed to do the trick. So why are we using $2 instead of $1

Comment: Because `$1` is taken by `(html|php)` captured group.